# Using part of a view in a different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to do the following and I can't figure it out. I have a controller with a view that shows a list of data. I would like to show that list of data on the home page. Is there any way to use the view of that list of data in the controller of the home page?

Comment: make it as a partial view and use renderpartialview method

Comment: yes but wouldn't result that in two 'seperate' lists of data? They show the same data but they aren't connected. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: you want to show the same list in both pages ?

Comment: If it's possible, yes.

Comment: using a partial view would mean the data to show the list is always from the same place, they will be the same view, the code is then only written in one place. Not sure what you mean by connected but the same code is rendered on both pages, it will not 'connect' them.

Comment: that's how it will execute. if you render partial view in same page it will show the same data in both pages

Answer (score 0):

You want to achieve two (or more) models to render in one view? If yes, then here is your answer.

Let's suppose that you have two models, `Book` and `Movie`

```
   public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    }


    public class Movie
    {
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

And then you want to get all Books and all Movies in one view. So create new class (for example in new folder named `ViewModels` and your class name can be anything, but let's name it for example `ViewModel`. In your class ViewModel write your `Book` and `Movie` model.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

If you want also to display list you need to specify IEnumerable list, here is for `Books` and `Movies`.

And finally in your controller you can simply write:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            var viewModel = new ViewModel
            {
                Movies = db.Movies.ToList(),
                //you can also do this:
                Movies = db.Movies.Where() //and so on
                Books = db.Books.ToList()
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

And `@model` for your view will be

```
@model MovieSubtitles.ViewModels.ViewModel
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying you currently have something like:

```
public DataController() {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
        .. load data
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

If you convert data list to a `PartialView` you can then use that in any other view, eg:

```
public DataController() {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult DataPartial()
    {   
        .. load data
        return Partial(data);
    }
}
```

then in your original view, move out just the parts related to data into `DataPartial.cshtml` and in index.cshtml add call to the *action*:

```
@Html.Action("DataPartial");
```

You can then re-use this partial/action anywhere you want by calling it as above, but also specifying the controller

```
public HomeController() {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
        return View();
    }
}
```

and home\index.cshtml:

```
@Html.Action("DataPartial", "Data")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I figured it out. I made a partial view and I implemented that partial view in both index views (from home and the actual page of the list of data)